# How can I see the name and password of my wifi using ethernet cable connection

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless

How I can retrieve the name and password of wifi. I am connected to a router via cable. Is there any way in ubuntu to get this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the Wifi password of a known connection. Simply go to:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

You will see all the saved connection profiles there, and you open it with root previliege:

`sudo cat some-ap-profile`

The password will be in the **[802-11-wireless-security]** section, see the **psk=** part:

```
[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
auth-alg=open
psk=HERE-IS-THE-PASSWORD
```

Comment: Passwords in plain-text??? O.O

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, in plain-text, the only protection is the root access, but if you mount it on another system as a normal data drive...